# scroll to top of newly generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So in my site, when a button is clicked,I dynamically generate a div, which contains a grid of images. It goes like this:

```
$('.prod-images').click(function(){
   var prodImages = generateProdImagesGrid(this);
   $('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).show();
});
```

This works fine. And I have another button which will close this div on click.

Now this div can be taller than the screen and require vertical scrolling. The problem is that because of all the CSS/styles in this page, this div always opens only at the scroll position where it was closed. So when I open it first time, it is scrolled to the top and everything is fine. Now, suppose I scroll this div halfway down and then close it. Next time when it is opened, it opens at that scroll position.

I tried doing:

```
$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).scrollTop(0).show();
```

This does not work (at least in chrome) because the div is not fully rendered when the scrollTop() call is executed.

The only way I can make this work is to give a long delay between the div rendering and the scrollTop call like so:

```
$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).show();
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('#prod-images-grid').scrollTop(0);
},10000); //call scrollTop after 10 seconds
```

As you can imagine, this is not at all a good solution. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can render the div so that when its visible, it is scroll to its top position?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).show().scrollTop(0);`?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: I believe I have, im trying it once more right now...

Comment: Nope did not work. I am sure it is supposed to under regular circumstances...but then the divs in this page are under duress...

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).scrollTop(0).show();
```

means that it's the `<div id="prod-images-grid">` which gets scrolled; since this div has no content, it cannot be scrolled.
Rather do:

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).show();
```

The `0` argument of `scrollTop` can of course be modified to point to the position of the document where you want your dynamically generated `div` to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle a function after the contents is showing whith this propety of .show():

```
$( ".target" ).show(interval, handler);
```

Like this:

```
$('#prod-images-grid').html(prodImages).show(1, function() {
        $('#prod-images-grid').scrollTop(0);
});
```

(you can change 1 for any other value)

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers as these are considered to be of low quality. Add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen fixed, sorry for my english.